# Como recuperar um array gravado no localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

```
var pessoa = ["Bonito","Alto","Magro"];
Window.localStorage.setItem('pessoa',JSON.stringify(pessoa))

pessoa=[null]
```

Agora eu quero recuperar esse valor *`Bonito,Alto,Magro`* um por um , que não está mais na variável e sim no `localstorage` nessa variável abaixo

```
var pessoaAntiga =
```

Answer (score 10):

Você precisa fazer o parse da sua string para JSON:

```
pessoaAntiga = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('pessoa'))
```

Answer (score 4):

> Não sei se foi um erro de digitação aqui, mas o objeto `window` é tudo
>   em minúsculas (você colocou o "W" em maiúscula, o que vai resultar em
>   erro).

Não precisa usar parse de JSON, basta colocar no `localStorage` a array direto que ela já é salva em forma de string.

Ou seja, ao usar:

```
var pessoa = ["Bonito","Alto","Magro"];
window.localStorage.setItem('pessoa', pessoa);
```

O valor do `localStorage` será a array em forma de string:

```
"Bonito","Alto","Magro"
```

E para recuperar você usa `.getItem()` e `.split(",")` para converter em array novamente (**se não houver vírgula no meio das palavras da array**):

```
var pessoaAntiga = window.localStorage.getItem('pessoa').split(",");
```

Comment: Esse método deve ser usado com cuidado, se alguma string no array conter vírgula, o `split` não retornará o valor esperado. E só pra ficar explícito, não é que `Window` esteja errado, mas `Window` se refere ao tipo (função construtora), equanto `window` ao valor (objeto)

Comment: Verdade amigo. Vou reavaliar a resposta. Obg!